A short "Detective story" without detectives but with a Fantasy element
I call it a "Detective story" because I read it in a detective stories magazine in French I borrowed in a "street library" then I returned it there. I had to be "before Covid" because I have stopped doing that since January 2020. But not much earlier than that, probably in 2019. The magazine, however, was rather old. And probably contains only translations from English.
There are no detectives, just two criminals on the one side, and on the other side two people who took justice into their own hands, which, technically makes them criminals, too (one of them was quite possibly a criminal even before). But the Fantasy aspect is crucial, so I think this is on-topic.
The POV character is a petty thief. But he is an accomplice to a real sociopath. The sociopath owns a dog, which he trained to be extremely ferocious. They haunt (without the dog, of course) dog tracks, selling "advices" (which they, themselves, don't put their money on) to newbies and picking pockets.
They notice one bettor who regularly makes money. He does not win on every race, but on the average, he manages to support a (very modest) living just with his bets. And this is all the more surprising that he does not look very clever, and this is a polite way to put it. So the sociopath decides to kidnap him and use the ferocity of his dog to torture him and find his secret. The POV character does what he is told to do, but he is not so keen about it.
The kidnapping goes well, they take him to their isolated cabin. But when the sociopath orders his dog to bite his prisoner, the latter starts to bark, and the dog does not bite him. The sociopath turns to his accomplice and asks him if perchance he had fed the dog, reducing his ferocity. The POV character denies having even approached the dog he terribly fears. During this exchange their prisoner manages to escape. The sociopath orders his dog to pursue him, but the dog doesn't budge.
Sometime later, a knock on the door of the cabin. They open to a big gun held by a big guy who looks a bit like their victim, but without the "not so clever" look. Behind him, their victim himself. The big guy asks "Bro, are these the two men who tried to hurt you ?" "Yes". The POV character says "We did not mean harm, we just wanted to ask him about his secret". "Well, I can tell you: my brother can talk to dogs, and they give him advices. The dogs are not perfect judges of themselves, so he does not win in every race. But he has enough insider information to make just enough money to be independent. He does not harm anyone, you can see he has pure soul. So you are going to pay for your cruelty to him. Bro, tell the dog to kill his master !" The victim barks a bit and the dog goes to the throat of the sociopath. IIRC, the POV character runs for his life, and the brothers do not send the dog after him.

"Mon frère peut parler aux chiens", etc presumably.

Yes, I read it in French. Presumably, that was the very sentence of the big guy. Provided the translator was not Belgian. In that case, it would be "Mon frère sait parler aux chiens".
